# Pop up on multiple mouseover

Tags: jquery

I have to create an 'X' that pops up over the top right div that is moused over. There are multiple divs that I need this to happen on, on the page. I have been able to achieve this on one div with the following very simple JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".imagetrigger").mouseover(function() {
        $(".xdiv").fadeIn();
    })

    $(".xdiv").mouseover(function() {
        $(".xdiv").show();
    })

    $(".imagetrigger").mouseout(function() {
        $(".xdiv").fadeOut();
    })
});
```

But, I don't want to have to write this out over and over again for all the divs on the page. The `xdiv` would also have to move position to be positioned correctly with the other divs and I was thinking of achieving this by using `.addclass` to add a new class to the `xdiv` with the updated margin positioning.

I appreciate any help or guidance offered.

After some further investigation I was able to get it to work. 
My JQuery now reads as following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".preview").hover(
      function () {
        $(".xdiv",this).show();
      },
      function () {
        $(".xdiv",this).hide();
      }
  );

});
```

I am still not sure why using the .children selector wasn't working and I will look into that, but the above work for me. Thanks for the help folks. I will be putting this in as the answer after the 6-8 hour cool down period is over.

Comment: Perhaps an approach you can take is to make the div's you want to have the cross over have an absolutely position div inside them. When you want the x to appear you can either give it a greater z-index value to appear over the top. Or change another css attribute to appear over the content on the div

Comment: Ah, sorry for not being clear. I need the X to be positioned to the top right of the div rather than completely in front of it. I have edited the original post to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to what i think you need.

What it does is (on mouseover) shows the cross in the top-right corner and hides it on mouseleave. You could then have a click function on the cross in the corner to do something from there.

HTML

```
<div id="box1" class="clickable">
  <div class="cross"></div>

  YOUR CONTENT
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.clickable
  {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
  }
div.cross
  {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-image:YOUR CROSS IMAGE
    display:none;
  }
```

Javascript (using jQuery Library)

```
$(".clickable").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).children(".cross").show();
  },
  function () {
    $(this).children(".cross").hide();
  }
);
```

Comment: Hmm, my only issue with this is that when I try to use the .children rather than the absolute selectors it wont work which I guess is my own DOM problem.

Comment: This is much better than suggested in OP. Simply create an empty div in all the divs that you want to have a cross on it.

Answer (score 0):

when showing and hiding the "xdiv" don't use absolute selectors but based on your html use `.next()` `.find()` , `.children()` etc.

f.ex; (assumed some html...)

```
<div class="imagetrigger">
<span class="xdiv"></span>
</div>

$(".imagetrigger").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).children(".xdiv").fadeIn();
})
```

this way you'll show only the xdiv you want

Answer (score -1):

Sorted. My JQuery now reads as following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".preview").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).append('<div class="xdiv"></div>');

    },
  function () {
    $(".xdiv",this).remove();
  }
  );

});
```

As you can see I am now appending and removing the cross div rather than showing and hiding it as I need this effect to happen on quite a few elements on the page, and this saves me from having to copy and paste in the div for the 'x' twenty or so times.